# How to create a list of links in c#?

Tags: c#, repeater, hyperlink, data-binding

I'm trying to create a simple hyperlink list with a [RepeaterItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.aspx) (I'm not particular to a RepeaterItem, so if there are better ways...).

I'm pretty much using the code from the MSDN documentation linked above, but I have a simple problem, I'm using the `<% %>` control wrong:

```
Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

<li><asp:HyperLink id="navListItem" runat="server"
NavigateUrl="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Url") %>">
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text") %></asp:HyperLink></li>
```

Apparently I cannot use <% within another asp.net tag.

What would be the "correct" way to create a list such as:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/linknumber1.html">Link Text 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/linknumber2.html">Link Text 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/linknumber3.html">Link Text 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

The Url & Link text I get from a resource file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either remove the double quotes for the `NavigateUrl` property or use a single quotes there instead:

```
NavigateUrl=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Url") %>
```

or

```
NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Url") %>'
```

and this should work.